# Open source tool for zipped file content searching?

Tags: c#, search, zip

Are there any open source tools for searching the contents of zipper files such as tars,7z,rar etc? Any API/projects developed in C#?

---

EDIT:
OK
So I found a link that provides a package for windows office 2010 "Office 2010 filter packs" that do a content search of the files. Is there an API for this that I can use for adding the searching functionality to my code in VS 2010?
http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/search-contents-zip-docs-windows-7/

Comment: Please don't add "C#" to the end of your titles. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably:

http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/

(SharpZipLib, formerly NZipLib) is a Zip, GZip, Tar and BZip2 library written entirely in C# for the .NET platform. It is implemented as an assembly (installable in the GAC), and thus can easily be incorporated into other projects (in any .NET language).

Also, it's "free as in beer" :)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean some program that can help you see and extract the said files, 7ZIP is a great, open-source program: http://www.7-zip.org/
It has an SDK in different languages here: http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html